# Ubuntu 16.04 vs 18.04 regarding CIFS

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, mount, cifs, nas

In Ubuntu 16.04 I was able to mount using fstab my network attached storage buffalo. The general configuration was that I had several symbolic links to locations on the NAS. This way when away from home there was no access, but no real impact since every local user still had their home directory on their individual laptops. I have added a new laptop to the ecosystem and have installed Ubuntu 18.04 but mounting the NAS like I did in 16 is just not working the same. 18 Seems to have the ability to see the NAS just fine and when I connect to it I am then able to see the icons of the NAS Folders as ethernet ports just fine. My issue is that I can't get those same locations to mount using fstab and them using symbolic links in each PC's home directory for that user.

Maybe there is just a better way to architect this?

Thank you for any advise you can give me.

Edited: Fixed title and tags.

--Tim

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. I was just not remembering all the steps I took to make it happen.

Here is what I did that got it all working as I had:

apt-get install cifs-utils

reboot (not sure if it is necessary)

in /etc/fstab added entries like:
//192.168.0.118/Pictures    /mnt/Pictures       cifs vers=1.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,suid,credentials=/etc/credentials 0 0

created an /etc/credentials file:

username={username}

password={password}

created mount point:
/mnt/Pictures

(not sure if this was necessary but I chmoded the mount point to 777)

renamed Pictures in home directory

symbolic link:

ln -s /mnt/Pictures

mount -a

I was then able to: ls -al Pictures

and saw all the directories we have setup that we have saved pictures on the NAS.

Any constructive feedback as to how I could have done this better is welcome!

*edit for formatting

Comment: The heading mentions NFS (network file system) but I see only loading CIFS (a different file system namely SaMBa) without mention of `nfs-common` needed for NFS file use.  I personally noticed no differences with NFS between 16.04/18.04 but your answer doesn't seem to apply to NFS at all, instead only SaMBA/CIFS

Comment: It is my belief that you can edit your own questions (& answers) without restriction (not related to rep). The differences between 16.04/18.04 relate to SaMBa/CIFS because of *Wannacry* which whilst it didn't impact POSIX (ubuntu etc), it **did** allow exploitation of windows weaknesses - thus `vers=` differences were made to defaults just to better protect windows clients; POSIX just followed suit (thus 16.04 -> 18.04 diffs)